# Рекурсивный вывод бинарного дерева

Tags: c#

При рекурсивном выводе бинарного дерева выводится только корень(_head). Как исправить ?

```
public class BinaryTree<T>: IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> _head;
    private int _count;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return RevOrder(_head);
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    private IEnumerator<T> RevOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            yield break;

        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            RevOrder(node.Left);
        }
        if (node.Right != null)
        {
            RevOrder(node.Right);
        }
            
        yield return node.Value;
    }

    public int Count { get { return _count; } }
}
```

Comment: Вот так вот ? if (node.Left != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in RevOrder(node.Left))
                {

                }
            }

Comment: Ошибка CS1579 Оператор foreach не работает с переменными типа "IEnumerator<T>", так как "IEnumerator<T>" не содержит открытое определение экземпляра или расширения для "GetEnumerator".

Comment: foreach (var item in RevOrder(node.Left))
                {
                    yield return item.Value;
                }

Comment: Ошибка появилась, сверху написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо проитерироваться по поддеревьям и вывести их элементы. К сожалению, `foreach` отказыватеся работать с `IEnumerator`. Старый добрый `while`:

```
private IEnumerator<T> RevOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node == null)
        yield break;

    if (node.Left != null)
    {
        var it = RevOrder(node.Left);
        while (it.MoveNext()) {
            yield return it.Current;
        }
    }
    if (node.Right != null)
    {
        var it = RevOrder(node.Right);
        while (it.MoveNext()) {
            yield return it.Current;
        }
    }
        
    yield return node.Value;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало )

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант (проверьте сами, мне негде пока проверить)

```
public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> _head;
    private int _count;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return RevOrder(_head).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> RevOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            yield break;

        if (node.Left != null)      
            foreach(var n in RevOrder(node.Left)) yield return n;
        
        if (node.Right != null)
            foreach(var n in RevOrder(node.Right)) yield return n;
        
        yield return node.Value;
    }

    public int Count { get { return _count; } }
}
```

Comment: Не работает( Ошибка CS1579 Оператор foreach не работает с переменными типа "IEnumerator<T>", так как "IEnumerator<T>" не содержит открытое определение экземпляра или расширения для "GetEnumerator".

Comment: значит вам надо лучше копипастить, [все компилируется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3uEy.png)

Comment: @tym32167 у вас в ответе `RevOrder` возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`, а оригинальный метод автора имеет возвращаемый тип `IEnumerator<T>` , я думаю @twintwinterrors просто скопировал тело функции

Comment: @iKuzmychov все так, я посчитал, что возвращать `IEnumerable<T>` из метода имеет больше смысла. Я потому и привел класс полностью, чтобы можно было просто скопировать и вставить.